# How allow moderators to give a rebuke to user

Tags: 7

I'd like to allow moderators to give a rebuke for users. If user has e.g. 3 rebukes, the account of user should be removed or blocked - automatically or moderator should be inform about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module for that. You can set flag for users or posts created by users or something else as per your requirement.

Use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to set rule on flagging & their counter value. There is very nice tutorial series on flag [here](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/703) by Johan Falk. You can see his rules tutorials to have better understanding about setting rules based on flagging.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'll go through the tutorial.

Comment: Unfortunately, every page in tutorial you recommended isn't found.

Comment: Can't you access next tut by clicking on the given link under next items in right hand side?

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry.

Comment: I read about it, yet there is too much information. Could you give me some directions how can I do it with Flag module.